# Calling a jQuery function on an external file for all the images on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to make a web page with images, which should provide the exact functionality of other pages on the same site. I could do that, except image enlarging feature on it.

Images should be enlarged on a popped-up box. For that, on the other pages a js file is used. (Attached)

The way I have tried is below. Since the other pages' codes are messy I couldn't grab exact thing to do. Help on this is much appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      var productThumbImage = $('.search_holder .product-enlarge-trigger img');

      productThumbImage.each(function() {
        // Get on screen image
        var screenImage = $(this);

        // Create new offscreen image to test
        var theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = screenImage.attr("src");

        // Get accurate measurements from that.
        var imageWidth = theImage.width;
        var imageHeight = theImage.height;

        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
          $(this).addClass('thumbCheckLandscape');
        }
      });
    });

    $(".product-enlarge-trigger img").hover(function() {
      alert('aaa');
    });

    $('body').removeClass();
    detectThumbs();

    function detectThumbs() {
      var productThumbImage = $('.product-enlarge-trigger img');
      alert(productThumbImage);

      productThumbImage.each(function() {
        var thumbCheck = $(this).attr('src');
        thumbCheck = thumbCheck.split('/');
        thumbCheck = thumbCheck[2];
        thumbCheck = thumbCheck.replace("%20", "");;

        $(this).parent().addClass(thumbCheck);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Enlarge/image.enlarge.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .tablet_thumb_landscape.thumbCheckLandscape {
      margin-top: 16px;
      width: 117px !important;
    }
    .thumbCheckLandscape {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .product-enlarge-trigger img {
      width: 7%;
      position: static !important;
    }
    .item_thumb_wrapper {
      height: 186px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.99);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.99);
      box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.99);
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      border-bottom: 8px solid #c8c7c8;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .enlarge_thumb_close {
      width: 33px;
      height: 33px;
      right: -16px;
      top: -16px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      background: url(../../../Images/Structure/search_enlarge_close.png)top left no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      z-index: 1001 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item_thumb_wrapper">
    <img src="aa\xxx.jpg" class="resize" width="250" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-enlarge-trigger">
    <img src="aa\xxx.jpg" class="resize" width="250" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="aa\xxx.jpg" class="resize" width="250" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

External js file

```js
// Plugin Definition
$.fn.productEnlarge = function(options) {
  var defaults = {
      'fadeInSpeed': 300,
      'lastRowClass': 'last',
      'overlayDiv': 'item-overlay-global',
      'enlargeDiv': 'product-scroll-enlarge'
    }
    // Extend our default options with those provided
  var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

  var getScrollTop = function() {
    var ScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    if (ScrollTop == 0) {
      if (window.pageYOffset)
        ScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
      else
        ScrollTop = (document.body.parentElement) ? document.body.parentElement.scrollTop : 0;
    }
    return ScrollTop;
  }

  var getViewportHeight = function() {
    var viewportheight;
    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
    }
    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
      'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
      viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }
    // older versions of IE
    else {
      viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }
    return viewportheight;
  }

  /*** sniff the UA of the client and show hidden div's for that device ***/
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  var windowwidth = $(window).width();

  var checker = {
    android: ua.match(/Android/),
    appleiPad: ua.match(/iPad/)
  };
  if (windowwidth <= 660) {
    //if (checker.android){
    // do nothing
  } // end UA detection
  else {

    // For every trigger passed bind our events
    return this.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.mouseover(function() {
        var hover_link = $(this).parent().attr('href');
        //var hover_call = $(this).parent().attr('rel');
        var hover_call = $(this).attr('rel');
        //alert (hover_link);
        // Create our overlay div
        //$('body').append('<a class="enlarge_thumb_close">Close</a><a href="' + hover_link + '" class="' + opts.overlayDiv + ' ' + opts.enlargeDiv + '"></a>');
        $('body').append('<a href="javascript://" onclick="' + hover_call + '" class="' + opts.overlayDiv + ' ' + opts.enlargeDiv + '"></a>');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.card-link').addClass('cardTitleSelected');
        //$(this).parent().parent().find('.card-link').appendTo('.product-scroll-enlarge');
        //$('.cardTitleSelected').appendTo('.product-scroll-enlarge');
        //$('.cardTitleSelected').show();

        var product_target_title = $(this).parent().parent().find('.card-link span');
        //$('.product-scroll-enlarge').append('<div class="enlarge_title"><div class="et_text_wrap">'+ product_target_title.html() +'<br><strong>A6</strong> &pound;1.79 / <strong>A4</strong> &pound;2.99 / <strong>A3</strong> &pound;5.99</div></div>');
        $('.enlarge_title').hide().remove();
        $('.product-scroll-enlarge').append('<div class="enlarge_title"><div class="et_text_wrap">' + product_target_title.html() + '</div></div>');
        //alert(product_target_title.html());
        $('body').append('<div class="enlarge_thumb_close"></div>');


        // Get our targets
        var target = $('.' + opts.overlayDiv);

        // Set a fallback bind to remove this new target on mouseout
        target.mouseout(function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });

        var product_target = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.' + opts.enlargeDiv);


        if (product_target.length == 0) {
          return false;
        }


        $(target).html(product_target.html()).fadeIn(opts.fadeInSpeed);

        // Calculate our positioning
        var pos_top = (($(this).offset().top + ($(this).height() / 2)) - (target.height() / 2));
        var pos_left = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + 25;
        var totalwidth = pos_left + target.width() + 25;

        // If our image goes beyond our viewport width or has a class of 'last' flip our offset
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass(opts.lastRowClass) || totalwidth > document.body.offsetWidth) {
          pos_left = ($(this).offset().left - target.width()) - 30;
        }

        var totalheight = (pos_top - getScrollTop()) + parseInt(target.height());
        //var totalheight = ((pos_top - getScrollTop()) + ($(this).height() / 2)) - parseInt(taget.height() / 2);
        var windowHeight = getViewportHeight();

        // If our image goes beyond our window height
        if (totalheight > windowHeight) {
          var minusval = parseInt(totalheight) - windowHeight;
          pos_top = pos_top - (minusval + 30);
        }

        // If our image is less than the product height, display below
        if (totalheight < target.height()) {
          pos_top = getScrollTop() + 50;
        }

        // Set our positional coordinates
        $(target).css('top', pos_top).css('left', pos_left);

        setTimeout(function() {
          //do something special
          var mainimagewidth = $('.item-overlay-global img').width();
          $('.enlarge_thumb_close').css('top', pos_top - 16).css('left', pos_left + mainimagewidth - 16);
        }, 100);

        $('.enlarge_thumb_close').click(function() {
          $this.hide().remove();
          $('.' + opts.overlayDiv).hide().remove();
          $('.enlarge_thumb_close').hide().remove();
        });

      });



      $this.mouseout(function() {
        var windowwidth = $(window).width();
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var checker = {
          appleiPad: ua.match(/iPad/)
        };
        if (windowwidth <= 440 || checker.appleiPad) {

        } else {
          $('.' + opts.overlayDiv).hide().remove();
          $('.enlarge_thumb_close').hide().remove();
          $('.enlarge_title').hide().remove();
        }
        //$('.cardTitleSelected').appendTo('.product-scroll-enlarge');
        //$('.cardTitleSelected').hide();
        //$('.product-scroll-enlarge .cardTitleSelected').after(''+ $this +' .shortlistSave');
      });

      $('.enlarge_thumb_close').click(function() {
        $('.' + opts.overlayDiv).hide().remove();
        $('.enlarge_thumb_close').hide().remove();
        $('.enlarge_title').hide().remove();
      });

      $('.item-overlay-global').click(function() {
        window.location = hover_link;
      });

    });

  }
};
```

Comment: and what issue are you facing, specifically? There's a lot of code there, which part is not working?

Comment: Actually I am new to jQuery. I feel the way I call it is wrong. I need to know the correct way of calling it. 

With my code nothing happens.

Comment: nothing happens _where_? Have you checked that _any_ of the code is executing? e.g. using console.log or alert in different places. Do you get any errors in the JS console? Perhaps if you put this into a JSFiddle it will be easier to debug.

Comment: With the help of google I tried all sorts of things you mentioned. I am not sure that I have done it correctly. And with alerts I found that it is not calling js.

Comment: Instead of `$(window).load(function() {` please can you try `$(function () {` - this should use jQuery's document ready function. Then the code should execute when the page is loaded. Put an alert immediately on the next line. Once we're sure it's definitely executing then we can see if any other problems exist.

Comment: Also, as well as the above, put all your script within the `$(function() { ... });` block, not just some of it. Some of your event handler declarations are outside it, so they will be running before the rest of the page has loaded, and thus trying to attach to elements which do not yet exist (because they are rendered below it). Putting the handler declarations within that block means jQuery will wait till the whole page is loaded before it tries to run that code and declare the event handlers etc.

Comment: As I said I am totally new to this field, jQuery. If time permits please pass me a small sample for this.

Comment: literally, replace the phrase `$(window).load(function() {`with `$(function () {`. On the line below that write `alert("document is ready");`. Then move that function's closing block  (the `});` which is just above `$(".product-enlarge-trigger img").hover(function() {`) to the line above `</script>`.

Comment: Did as you have asked. Now it pops up the alert which you have asked. And alert('aaa'); too.

But, resizing window (enlarge) is not getting anything. What else should I do.

Comment: I can see two obvious problems. 1. `var productThumbImage = $('.search_holder .product-enlarge-trigger img');` will not populate the productThumbImage variable. The selector does not match anything in your html. There's no class called search_holder mentioned anywhere. Also all the `<div>`s round your images have different classes. If you want it to loop through them all you should give them all the same class (possibly in addition to the classes you have now if necessary) and then use that class instead of `var productThumbImage = $('.search_holder .product-enlarge-trigger img');`

Comment: 2. `thumbCheck = thumbCheck.split('/');` is unlikely to split the string properly because all your image `src` tags use `\ ` instead of `/` so it won't match. `/` is correct for the web anyway.

Comment: 3. I can't see anywhere that you're actually using the productEnlarge function. It's defined in enlarge.js but not actually used anywhere as far as I can see.

Comment: If you're very new to jQuery (and javascript/html/css in general, it would appear), this is a relatively ambitious piece of work to start on. I suggest you learn a little more about it, do some tutorials and so on and then come back to it when you understand the general concepts better. Then if you are still stuck ask another question on SO with a more specific problem. Otherwise we will be here forever debugging it.